# Mimic gps location on windows server edition

Tags: windows, testing, gps, location, maps

I'm trying to change the default location of windows server edition vm, but I'm unable to do so.

I tried to change the gps location by changing the default location. In order to that I tried downloading the maps app but it can't be downloaded due to the server edition. Is there any other way to change the location of the vm.